# python can't catch KafkaException of confluent_kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Here is part of my code:

```
class KafkaProducer:

    def __init__(self):
    pass

    bootstrap_server_host = system_config.get_kafka_bootstrap_server()
    producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_server_host, "log.connection.close":False})

    @classmethod
    def send(cls, topic, key, value, data_type=None, uid=None):
        try:
            data = {"data": value, "createTime": long(time.time() * 1000)}
            if data_type is not None:
            data["type"] = int(data_type)
            if uid is not None:
            data["uid"] = long(uid)
            cls.producer.produce(topic, json.dumps(data), key)
            cls.producer.poll(0)
        except BufferError as e:
            logger.error('%% Local producer queue is full ' \
                         '(%d messages awaiting delivery): try again\n' %
                         len(cls.producer))
            raise e

class new_application_scanner():
　　 @classmethod
    def scan_new_application(cls):
        db_source = None
        try:
            db_source = DBConnector().connect()
            db_cur = db_source.cursor()

            ...

        　　　　KafkaProducer.send("RiskEvent", str(uid),
                   {"uid": uid, "country_id": user_info[1], "event_id": constant.RISK_EVENT_NEW_APPLICATION})

            ...
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            if db_source is not None:
            db_source.close()




def run_scan_new_application():
    while is_scan_new_application_active:
    try:
        logging.info("scan_new_application starts at %s",time.time())
        new_application_scanner.scan_new_application()
        logging.info("scan_new_application ends at %s", time.time())
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("new_application_scanner Error:%s",format(e))
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
    time.sleep(10)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_scan_new_application, name='run_scan_new_application', args=([]))
t1.start()
```

I have a kafka group of two servers. when I restart two servers one by one ,KafkaProducer.send() throws KafkaException(maybe some bug in confluent_kafka), and there are some exception logs.

The strange thing is the Exception continues to throw out of scan_new_application and there are exception logs in run_scan_new_application too. Even the thread stopped.Here is the exception logs:

```
2017-12-21 07:11:49 INFO pre_risk_control_flow.py:71 pid-16984 scan_new_application starts at 1513840309.6
2017-12-21 07:11:49 ERROR new_application_scan.py:165 pid-16984 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/data/code/risk/Feature_Engine/data_retrive/pre_risk_control_flow/new_application_scan.py", line 163, in scan_new_application
    {"uid": uid, "country_id": user_info[1], "event_id": constant.RISK_EVENT_NEW_APPLICATION})
  File "/home/ubuntu/data/code/risk/Feature_Engine/data_retrive/kafka_client/Producer.py", line 27, in send
    cls.producer.produce(topic, json.dumps(data), key)
KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_UNKNOWN_TOPIC,val=-188,str="Unable to produce message: Local: Unknown topic"}

2017-12-21 07:11:49 ERROR pre_risk_control_flow.py:75 pid-16984 new_application_scanner Error:KafkaError{code=_UNKNOWN_TOPIC,val=-188,str="Unable to produce message: Local: Unknown topic"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying client is raising `KafkaException KafkaError{code=_UNKNOWN_TOPIC..}` because it (now) knows the requested topic does not exist in the cluster (and auto topic creation is disabled). This is expected.

You are seeing the exception in `run_scan_new_application` because you are not catching `KafkaException` in `send()`.

Comment: I caught `Exception` in `new_application_scanner` , however i can still see `KafkaException` in `run_scan_new_application`

Comment: Try upgrading to v0.11.5, previous versions had KafkaException not properly sub-classed from BaseException